# How can you filter a list of dictionary in python with list as value

Tags: python, dictionary

#List of dictionary

```
List_of_dict = [
    {'id': 1,'Name':Tom, 'Data':[10,20,30,40,50],'Value':[1,2,3,4,5] },
    {'id': 2,'Name':Jack, 'Data':[10,20,30,],'Value':[3,4] },
    {'id': 3,'Name':Nancy, 'Data':[10,20],'Value':[3,4,5] },
    {'id': 4,'Name':Jack, 'Data':[20,],'Value':[1]}
]
```

Quest : Want to create a filter for data 30 and value 3
Expected - 1:

```
Output_dict = [{'id': 1,'Name':Tom, 'Data':[10,20,30,40,50],'Value':[1,2,3,4,5] },{'id': 2,'Name':Jack, 'Data':[10,20,30,],'Value':[3,4]
```

used this >>

```
Output_dict = [out for out in List_of_dict if  out['Data'] == [30] and out['Value'] == [3] ]
```

I don't get desired output with above

Also how do I create filter for Data: 20' and Value:3 or 4
Expected - 2:

```
[{'id': 1,'Name':Tom, 'Data':[10,20,30,40,50],'Value':[1,2,3,4,5] },{'id': 2,'Name':Jack, 'Data':[10,20,30,],'Value':[3,4] },{'id': 3,'Name':Nancy, 'Data':[10,20],'Value':[3,4,5] }]
```

Comment: @enke Better don't hide data behind a scrollbar...

Comment: Although the whole question should just be "Why is `[10,20,30,40,50] == [30]` false?", then that would be a no-issue. Definitely not the expected [mre]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it's searching for an exact match: `out['Data'] == [30]`. You need to use `in` instead like `30 in out['Data']`.

So it could be changed to:

```
out1 = [d for d in List_of_dict if (30 in d.get('Data', [])) and (3 in d.get('Value', []))]
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1,
  'Name': 'Tom',
  'Data': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
  'Value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
 {'id': 2, 'Name': 'Jack', 'Data': [10, 20, 30], 'Value': [3, 4]}]
```

For the second case, you can use `set.intersection` to check if 3 or 4 exist in any `d['Value']`:

```
out2 = [d for d in List_of_dict if (20 in d.get('Data', [])) and (set(d.get('Value', [])) & {3, 4})]
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1,
  'Name': 'Tom',
  'Data': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
  'Value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
 {'id': 2, 'Name': 'Jack', 'Data': [10, 20, 30], 'Value': [3, 4]},
 {'id': 3, 'Name': 'Nancy', 'Data': [10, 20], 'Value': [3, 4, 5]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response out1 works fine but out2 just filters for value 3. I wish to  filter the dict with data:20 and value can 3 OR 4 .

Comment: @AbhaySood updated. see if it works now

Answer (score 0):

You are testing against lists that have no match in your data.

Use e.g.

```
Output_dict = [out for out in List_of_dict if  30 in out['Data'] and 3 in out['Value']]
```